# How to solve C++ Warning C4251

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to expose MyClass with dllexport. But I have this Warning(C4251).

**Code**

```
class MyClassImpl
{
public:
private:
    const String Name;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass {
public :
private: 
    const MyClassImpl data;
};
```

**Warning**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4251
'MyClass::data': class 'MyClassImpl' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'MyClass'
```

**C/C++ - Command line**

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /GL /Zc:preprocessor /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "MYTESTLIB_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /std:c17 /Gd /Oi /MD /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\MytestLib.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

**Linker - Command line**

```
/OUT:"I:\XProjects\MyTestLibWindows\x64\Debug\MyTestLib.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"I:\XProjects\MyTestLibWindows\x64\Debug\MyTestLib.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "botan.lib" "icudt.lib" "icuin.lib" "icuio.lib" "icutest.lib" "icutu.lib" "icuuc.lib" /IMPLIB:"I:\XProjects\MyTestLibWindows\x64\Debug\MyTestLib.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /PGD:"I:\XProjects\MyTestLibWindows\x64\Debug\MyTestLib.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:NO /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\MyTestLib.dll.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\MyTestLib.iobj" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\MyTestLib.ilk" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"I:\XProjects\MyTestLibWindows\modules\ICU4c-73.1-Windows-x64-Release\lib64" /LIBPATH:"I:\XProjects\MyTestLibWindows\modules\Botan-2.19.3-Windows-x64-Debug\lib" /TLBID:1
```

How I have to create a DLL interface?

Comment: What are your project configurations/compiler flags?

Comment: It is a warning, not an error.  The field is private, so reasonable odds that this won't cause a problem at runtime.  Consider the pimpl pattern.

Comment: The "pointer to implementation pattern" (or "pimpl pattern") would have a `const MyClassImpl* data;` **pointer** in the client-facing class.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is telling you that there's *nothing to export*. When you apply `__declspec(dllexport)` to a class, that is the same as applying `__declspec(dllexport)` to every method of the class.

You don't have any methods declared.

See [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4251)